# Load CSV file to mySQL using NiFi

Tags: mysql, etl, apache-nifi

I am trying to load CSV file into mySQL database but failing doing this when there are fields with empty strings like ''.
My Flow file looks like this -->
[image: Flow]

My CSVreader configuration looks like this -->
[image]

The table schema and data that I try to import with CSV-->

[image]

I created this table as CSV and try to load it into another DB with same schema but fails because of the second line with name ='' , for some reason NiFi reads this as NULL which isn't possible and not the right data.

How can I fix this?

Edit:
That's how the CSV file looks like in editor-->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDuXs.png)

```
"id","name","age"
1,"ggg",
2,"",
```

Comment: Show how cvs file looks like where nifi is failing

Comment: "id","name","age"
1,"ggg",
2,"",

That's how the CSV looks like.

Comment: please put this into your question with format.

Comment: @daggett it's there now

Answer (score 2):

You have left name column empty in the second insert statement. Is not it normal to looks null in the csv?